# Where is the temporary stash entry created by `git rebase --autostash`?

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-stash

I am used to run `git rebase --autostash`. For several reasons (conflict, edition, etc...) I may be interrupted during the rebase. I expect to see the autostashed content in the output of `git stash list`. But it is not. Where the temporary stash entry is located? How to see it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the rebase is going, the autostash is stored in :  `.git/rebase-merge/autostash`.

Since this file is stored under `.git/`, and is a valid reference file, you can use `rebase-merge/autostash` as a name to point to the autostash :

```
git log --oneline --graph rebase-merge/autostash

# you can also use it with 'git stash show' or 'git stash apply' :
git stash show rebase-merge/autostash
git stash apply rebase-merge/autostash
```

You can also "insert" it in the regular stash by manually calling `git update-ref refs/stash` :

```
git update-ref -m "autostash" refs/stash rebase-merge/autostash
```

---

*note* : before reading your question I also thought the autostash was as a regular stash, I just found out about the tricks above by inspecting the content of `.git/rebase-merge/`.

The hacks above work at the moment (git version 2.31), I don't think you should count them as a rock solid, forever stable feature -- for example the internal structure of the `.git/rebase-merge/` directory isn't part of the documentation.

---

and obviously, if you run `git rebase` from a terminal, you can also see the hash of the autostash in the command's output :

```
$ git rebase -i master 
Created autostash: 2acfb51
...
```

Comment: The stash will also be worktree-dependent. `rebase-merge/autostash` will be the one for the main worktree. The temporary directory for rebase has moved around in the past, so I think your advice to be wary of changes is good. :-)